# Maven test for only provided package

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project. I want to test only one package but that package may depend on other packages.
For better explanation, I created an example GitHub repository:
[GitHub Example Repository](https://github.com/Borjianamin98/TestRepo)

Running `mvn -pl module test` can cause problem because of dependencies of `module`. Instead of that, I must run `mvn -pl module -am test` but this command run `test` for my module and **all dependents** modules (in my example, run `test` for `dependent-module-1` and `dependent-module-2`).
Performance is crucial for me. I don't want to run test for dependents package when I want to run tests for only one module. So I decide to convert my command to:

```
mvn clean
mvn -pl module -am compile test-compile (or mvn -pl module -am package)
mvn -pl module test
```

It doesn't works and give errors because of not provided artifact.

I search a lot and I don't find anything. Please consider that I don't want to use `mvn install` at all. I don't want to move it to my repository.

Is it possible to help me? I don't know what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Please make a full working example project on Github otherwise it's hard to understand what you real problem is..?

Comment: I added an GitHub example.

Comment: Running those tests on local machine?

Comment: Yes. I have a server which can't connect to netwrok. I provided necessary dependencies in maven .m2 folder but I want to compile my modules based on target folder created by maven.